# Why visit https://graph.facebook.com/me/home can‘t get all data？

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When visit https://graph.facebook.com/me/home, facebook default limit, the display 25 data, but access to the simulator returned on the next page link， no data is returned.home obviously not just the 25 data, but show only 25, which is why it?

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean with the /home ?

If you want your information, keep only https://graph.facebook.com/me

And you should have a access token too.

Use this link to test graph urls.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

vote up if it help you.